# Can flyway proceed with execuition of scripts even if there is an exception?

Tags: java, flyway

I have 10 sql scripts to be executed using Flyway. If these is any error in the 7th script, I wan't Flyway to log a warning and proceed with the execution of 8th, 9th and the 10th script.

Please let me know if this is possible using Flyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. The design is based on a fail-fast approach. This is unlikely to change.